# Anylogic : not able to use stopDelay()

Tags: anylogic

I am building a railway station model. I want a train to depart when I click a button. I want to call stopDelay() for that but I am not sure how to do that and from which place.

Comment: Hi Anupam, welcome to SOF. Please check how to ask good questions, see link below. Your question is too vague. What do you want to achieve with stopDelay(), where are you calling it from currently, any errors? What research have you already done? very happy to help but we need more info :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question lacks information, the button has an action that you can use to place your java code. It is unknown how your trains are working but the following image may give you some light into what to do:
[image: delay and button]

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.